# Uploading static websites using Ruby on Rails and displaying them

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, rails-activerecord

I am wondering how to implement a showcase for users' code online. I'm building a Rails app and I want users to be able to upload code projects with multiple interacting files and allow them to be shown in-page. To give an example, I would like to be able to upload an Asteroids game written in javascript and rendered in an HTML canvas element; the files included in such a project are as follows:

```
Asteroids/
   |- asteroids.js
   |- app.js
   |- ship.png
   |- planet.png
   |- index.html
   |- underscore.min.js
   |- keymaster.min.js
```

Ideally I would be able to upload the containing folder and render the html file in an iframe with all the necessary js/image files accessible. I would like to know if this is possible and, if so, how it might be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want the users to be able to upload existing static web projects (html,js,css) and then showcase them by providing links to them.

First of all this is exactly what web-hosting providers have been doing for years by giving ftp or ssh access to respective directories in web-servers. except you will list all your sites on one page.

Coming to how you could do this from a web interface using ror (very general):

1. Provide a form to create a web-project. (create a dir in your public dir from the controller).
2. Similarly provide form to create folder structure. (not needed if all your users have files in one folder in that case skip to step 3).
3. Now in each of the created folders you could use jquery-file-upload combined with carrierwave gem in rails to upload multiple files to each of the folder.
4. Thats it, you should now be able create a list of projects you have in public dir and point users to them.
5. You can now also individual projects in iframes as you have complete projects including html sitting into you public folder.
6. Lastly be-ware or security threats involved in letting people upload code to your server. Its better to upload these files directly to amazon s3.

Here are some references that should get you started.

[Rails Cast on CarrierWave](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)

[Sample project showing jquery-file-upload integration with carrierwave in rails](https://github.com/n0ne/Rails-Carrierwave-jQuery-File-Upload)

[Sample project showing how to use amazon s-3 as a storage with jquery-file upload and carrirwave in rails](https://github.com/shaunakv1/Rails-Carrierwave-S3-jQuery-File-Upload)

Let me know if that helps, or I am way off the mark

Comment: Awesome! You've given me a good idea of how to approach this issue.

Comment: glad to be of help :)